# How to write excel file in java ignoring excel formulas?

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula

I'm using java to write excel file. Some of the cells starts with
"--" and when i open the file with excel it tries to generate formula from it
but fails and instead display `#NAME?`.

I've tried to `concat` a null char but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Excel interprets `--` as a formula. If you want to fill in `--` as a string, put an single quotation mark at the beginning: `'--`, so that Excel interprets it as a string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm looking for solution that won't affect the value inside the cells.